# In porting code to Angular2 with jquery and jqueryui I don't see the .draggable propery? why?

Tags: jquery-ui, angular, typescript

I have installed:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install jqueryui --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
npm install npm install @types/jqueryui --save
```

and in the source file:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
```

but still in the code:

```
public setupDragDrop(....) {
  $('span.task_header')
    .filter(function (index: number, ele: any) {
      ...
      return true;
    })
    .draggable(
      {
         ...
      });

 }
```

I only see TS2339: Property 'draggable' does not exist on type 'jQuery'.
So clearly I still don't know how to properly add jqueryui to typescript, since jqueryui extends the jquery interface and I would believe that the above should just work.

I have hunted high and low, but since typescript has morphed so much, the solutions I can find seem badly out of date.  any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

-- UPDATE ---
So I changed the import of 'jquery-ui' above to 
     import $ui from 'jquery-ui';

and the code to:

```
public setupDragDrop(....) {
  $ui('span.task_header')
    .filter(function (index: number, ele: any) {
      ...
      return true;
    })
    .draggable(
      {
         ...
      });

 }
```

and this seems to work fine.... and seems reasonable... 
Any thoughts? Is the right thing to do? and why is this necessary?